# Possible to get one of dependency version to insert into a filtered resource file?

Tags: maven, build, filter

I've a resource file, that is filtered by maven:

```
version=${project.version}
buildDate=${timestampFormatted}
buildBy=${user.name}   
fileEncoding=${file.encoding}
XX_LIB_VERSION = ${project.dependency.someName.version}
```

I would like to have one or more dependency and version used by the pom 
Is there any thing like *${project.dependency.someName.version}?*

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First extract desired dependencies' versions into a property (which is always a good idea):

```
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.1.0.RC2</org.springframework.version>
</properties>
```

And use it later in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Once this is done you can reference the property in filtered resource:

```
XX_LIB_VERSION=${org.springframework.version}
```

Comment: So for X dependencies i will have to declare X properties?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. Although I am not claiming this is the best approach. Spring is a good example here because you typically import several dependencies with the same version (only one property needed).