# Filtering a dependency's version in a maven POM file

Tags: java, maven, filtering

Is it possible to somehow include a dependency's version number in a pom's properties tag pair? I simply want to get hold of a dependency's version number. This is more or less an extension of this question:

[Possible to get one of dependency version to insert into a filtered resource file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825812/possible-to-get-one-of-dependency-version-to-insert-into-a-filtered-resource-fil)

This is basically what I want to achieve, but I don't want to have to explicitly write down the version number of the dependency I need - i.e. I should be able to inherit the version number of the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

Version is Mandatory for Dependency Management and dependency resolution.

but can ease you by mentioning version such a  way like

getting latest version all the time. getting version between specified range.  etc.

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency)

Comment: How would I be able to retrieve this to use in a properties file - by filtering or something else?

Comment: mention that in pom.xml instead as property inside <properties> ..</properties>

Comment: So how do I relate to the dependency when adding inside the properties tags?

Comment: <properties> <App.version> XYZ </App.version></properties> and use it wherever you need on pom like ${App.version}

Comment: Ok, I understand now - I suppose this will be my last resort option as I need to produce a number (rather a regex) that can be passed to a properties file.