# In maven, how to substitute resolved version in filtered resources?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Ok: I've done this: [Possible to get one of dependency version to insert into a filtered resource file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825812/possible-to-get-one-of-dependency-version-to-insert-into-a-filtered-resource-fil)

If the specified version of the dependency is a range, is it possible for the resource filter to substitute the resolved version, not the range specification?

In other words, from the answer to that other posted question,
such that maven property has:

```
<properties>
   <org.springframework.version>[3.1.0,3.2.0)</org.springframework.version>
</properties>
```

and, in resource 'somefile.txt': `XX_LIB_VERSION=${org.springframework.version}`

I want this result:`XX_LIB_VERSION=3.1.0.RC2`

not: `XX_LIB_VERSION=[3.1.0,3.2.0)`

Thanks and regards

Comment: +1 for the good corner-case question, but I'm not quite sure it's possible at all.